# How to handle command line args that have relations with argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

suppose I have a program called `myprog` that takes some filename as input, and I also want use command line args to set the open mode for each file.
For example

```
myprog --input a.txt --mode r --input b.txt --input c.txt --mode a
```

Which means open file `a.txt` with mode `r`, file `b.txt` doesn't have a --mode arg, so open it with default mode `r`, and for the file `c.txt`, use the `a` mode to open it.

Comment: If you are using pycharm you can specify command line arguments using settings.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Do you guarantee that for every `--input`, there is a corresponding `--mode`?  If so, then you could just use the `'append'` action on both `input` and `mode` and then `zip` the lists.  If not (which looks like the case based on your example), then things get a lot more difficult unless you're willing to restructure the commandline -- e.g. `myprog --input a.text r --input b.txt --input c.txt a ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky problem because argparse doesn't give you any way to know which `--input` a particular `--mode` is associated with.  You *could* change the structure of the command so that the filename and the mode are separated by a sentinel character:

```
myprog --input a.txt:r --input b.txt --input c.txt:a
```

Obviously this assumes you don't have files whose names end in `:<mode>` where `<mode>` is any acceptable file mode.  If this is an OK structure, then this becomes as simple as writing a custom action or type to parse the string and return a suitable object. e.g.

```
def parse_fstr(s):
    filename, _, mode = s.rpartition(':')
    return (filename, mode or 'r')
```

Other solutions could involve using `nargs='*'` and then parsing out the list of arguments passed.

---

Finally, to implement what you've *actually* asked for without too much difficulty, we need to make an assumption.  The assumption is that `argparse` will parse items from left to right.  Given the functionality of the library, that is the only reasonable choice for implementation as far as I can tell...

Given that implementation, we can do this with a custom type and a custom [Action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action).  The type is simply a structure to keep a `filename` and a `mode` grouped together.  We'll use `argparse` to construct a new instance of this type every time we hit an `--input` and append it to a list (This is supported out of the box by `argparse`).  Next, we'll write a custom action to update the `mode` of the last "file struct" in the list every time we encouter a `--mode` argument.

```
import argparse


class FileInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mode='r'):
        self.name = name
        self.mode = mode

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'FileInfo(name={!r}, mode={!r})'.format(self.name, self.mode)


class UpdateMode(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        try:
            last_file_info = namespace.input[-1]
        except IndexError:
            # No file-info added yet.  Error.
            parser.error('{} must come after an --input'.format(option_string or '--mode'))

        last_file_info.mode = values


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', action='append', type=FileInfo)
parser.add_argument('--mode', action=UpdateMode)
print(parser.parse_args())
```

I've chosen to throw an error if `--mode` shows up before any `--input`, but if 2 `--mode` follow an `--input`, I'm just overwriting the previous value.  If you wanted to more error checking, it'd be a simple matter of writing a little more code in the `FileInfo` class to make sure that no mode has already been set when you go to update the mode.

Comment: Yes, `parse_args` iterates through `argv` (`sys.argv[1:]`), alternatively handling positionals and optionals.  The  respective `nargs` control how many strings are given to each `Action`.  So your custom Action classes should  work as advertised.

Answer (score 0):

If the command line is like this:

```
myprog --input a.txt --mode r --input c.txt --mode a --input b.txt
```

It's ok to add some code like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', action='append')
parser.add_argument('--mode', action='append')
args = parser.parse_args()
args_dict = vars(args)
```

Then you can parse the args object, *args_dict* variable.  The value is like this:

```
$ python test.py --input test.txt --mode w --input test3.txt --input test2.txt --mode a
{'mode': ['w', 'a'], 'input': ['test.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test2.txt']}
```

You can iterate both *'input'* key and *'mode'* key in the *args_dict* variable, for the remain of input list(it's 'test2.txt' here), you can open it with 'r' mode.

But if your command line have to write something like:

```
myprog --input a.txt --mode r --input b.txt --input c.txt --mode a
```

I don't think it's easy to parse the b.txt with 'r' mode, because argparse don't know which mode is bind to the relative input...

---

Get inspiration from @mgilson 's comment and answer, I have found another way to define Action subclass, and make the *'mode'* input useful.

```
class ExtendReadOnlyAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        inputs = namespace.input
        modes = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        if modes is None:
            modes = []
        modes.extend(['r' for i in range(len(inputs) - len(modes))])
        modes[-1] = values
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, modes)
```

And the client code can be something like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparser.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', action='append')
parser.add_argument('--mode', action=ExtendReadOnlyAction)
args = parser.parse_args()
args_dict = vars(args)
```

Then we can parse the args object, *args_dict* variable more easier.  If the command line is like this:

```
$ python test.py --input test.txt --mode w --input test2.txt --input test3.txt --mode a
```

The result will be:

```
{'mode': ['w', 'r', 'a'], 'input': ['test.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt']}
```

In the other special way, if the command line is like this:

```
$ python test.py --input test.txt --mode w --input test2.txt --input test3.txt --input test4.txt
```

The result will be:

```
{'input': ['test.txt', 'test2.txt', 'test3.txt', 'test4.txt'], 'mode': ['w']}
```

And then you can parse the dict more easier, the 'test2.txt ~ test4.txt' in the input argument will have the default 'r' mode :)

Comment: This was my first thought too, but after thinking about it a little more, it's definitely possible (and surprisingly not even that hard).  Since `argparse` provides hooks to write your own actions, you can code up a state-machine via custom actions without too much difficulty.  See my answer :-)

Comment: @mgilson Very appreciate for your comment :)It's clearly and good point to solve this..But it make the *'mode'* value of parse_args result useless.  But that's not a very big problem I think.